# Is it possible to create GUI applications with c++ standard native library?

Tags: c++, user-interface, native

I am interested in GUI application development, and when i search for it i found the only way ahead of me is to master in frameworks like qt, wxWidgets, gtk+, win32 etc. Win32 is ofcourse a native way, but it only run on win pc.

Why c++ standard native libraries does not provide APIs for GUI development?, just like like java.

It has every functions of its own to make a fully featured GUI app..?

Comment: No, the c++ standard library has no notion of graphics.

Comment: What framework do you depend upon?

Comment: Do you want portable GUI or OS specific GUI?  Do you want minimal sized framework or do you want additional features?  Do you need animation support?  How much graphics hardware support do you need?  What are the various graphics hardware that you want to support?  What versions of OS do you need to support?  Do you need static libraries or dynamic libraries?  Too many questions to recommend a framework.  You should probably research using "c++ GUI framework" and investigate all the different frameworks that show up.

Answer (score 2):

Most platforms such as Windows, Mac OSX, Unix, Unix derivatives like Linux, and so forth, provide libraries of callable routines or objects which support GUI development on those platforms.

It might be nice to have a universal GUI library, but that would likely limit its features and aesthetics to a particular format and architecture which would necessarily have to exclude some of the most distinctive and useful features of the platform on which such applications would be used.

So one needs to select a platform for development and anticipate parallel development on alternative platforms. Sometimes aesthetics drives these decisions and sometimes capabilities and performance drives them.

Welcome to an endless adventure, good friend.

Comment: one plus for "endless adventure"

Comment: FYI, many embedded systems do not have GUI capabilities.  Also, there is no standard for graphical output.  A terminal with cursor positioning could be one end of the scale while a vector based terminal could be at the other end.  Not to mention all the various raster displays and their different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

No.

GUI require graphics. C++ does not require a graphical environment. Unless you implement an OS yourself with graphics drivers etc in C++ you will not be able to do that.

And if you do, you will have re-invented the wheel (Win32).

Edit: As for java it is practically an OS.